# NSMutableDictionary Removes same values from different array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Hi i am using the following code to remove objects from NSMutableDictionary, both dictionaries contains same array values, if i remove a value from D1 the same value get removed from D2 Automatically.
Help me out how to solve this,

```
NSMutableDictionary *D1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *D2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *arr_objs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ss",@"nn", nil];

[D1 setObject:arr_objs forKey:@"Keys"];
[D2 setObject:arr_objs forKey:@"Keys"];

[[D1 objectForKey:@"Keys"]removeObject:@"nn"];
```

Comment: `[[D1 objectForKey:@"Keys"]removeObject:@"nn"]; D2 = [D1 mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr_objs` is the same array in two dictionaries. This

```
NSMutableArray *arr_objs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ss",@"nn", nil];
NSMutableArray *arr_objsCopy = [arr_objs mutableCopy];

[D1 setObject:arr_objs forKey:@"Keys"];
[D2 setObject:arr_objsCopy forKey:@"Keys"];
```

should give you what you're looking for. Rather than storing the same array in two dictionaries, this example creates two identical arrays that can later be modified without affecting each other.